# Difference between the new Salesforce Platform Developer 1 certificate and the old Developer certification DEV-401

Tags: certification, dev401, certificates

I'm a little bit confused about the new Salesforce Platform Developer I certificate. Is it a replacement of the old developer certificate (DEV-401)? If so, does DEV-401 certified developers need to pass the new one to be recognized as Salesforce developers?

The same applies to the new Platform Developer II. Does it replace DEV-501?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You may like to watch following video.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?t=3&v=wM5Th-ComR4

**AppBuilder Transition Certification** focus on declarative skills. It do not focus on Visualforce at all now. It do focus on Lightning Introduction, Salesforce1 understanding, Sandbox and Packages.

**Platform Developer 1** focus on coding skills. It also focus on Introduction to Lightning.

There is no prerequisite for Platform Developer 1 certification now unlike DEV 501 for which we had to be certified developer was prerequisite.

**Platform Developer 2** focus on advanced coding skills and also has assignment.It also focus on Integration skills(SOAP API, REST API, Analytics API) now which were not tested earlier in Advanced Developer certification.

Answer (score 5):

Developer 401 is succeeded by App Builder. Developer 501 is succeeded by two exams namely Platform Developer 1 and Platform Developer 2.

If you hold Developer 401, you can take a transition exam and get the App Builder certification.

If you hold Developer 501, you can take transition exams of Platform Developer 1 and 2.

Hope it clarifies your confusion.

Comment: Actually, there's MUCH more content in the latter 2 exams than there was in the DEV-501 exam alone, including Process Builder (& when to use it vs workflow or visual flow) along with Lightning in the Platform Developer 1 Exam. That's part of why there's now three exams instead of two. The platform has grown and expanded far too much to only have the two exams.

Comment: Don't forget you have to pay to take a transition exam. Salesforce might have handled this a bit nicer: not only do we have to invest time, we also must pay money.

Comment: I am not sure whether we have to pay for transition of Dev 501 as i don't hold that certification but Dev 401 transition we need to pay.

Comment: If you hold the DEV501 certification, you don't need to pay for the combined transition exam to Platform Dev 1 and Platform Dev 2.

Comment: @Rob -You are correct, only the "New" App builder exam costs money as it is a "New Credential". Dev 401 (Salesforce Certified Developer) can take the transition Exam to "Platform I" for free. Only the new credential costs a fee

Answer (score 3):

The  Dev 401 certification doesn't test any of the Apex and Visualforce skills but the name says a Certified Force.com Developer. So now salesforce made the changes to this developer certification so that the Platform developer I certification test basic knowledge on Apex,Visualforce,Lightning. Where as the configuration skills is certified as Platform App Builder.

The topics for both the Platform Developer I and II certification is almost  similar but the developer II is advanced and you need a good experience in coding and also has the programming assignment followed by essay exam.