# What is the current scene with DEV 401?

Tags: dev401

Has DEV 401 been discontinued? what about dev maintainance exam? are we supposed to take it or not?

I answered platform 1 transition exam and have passed that. What is the whole new change, i am bit confused as the maintenance exam last date is approaching.

Comment: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/90357/difference-between-the-new-salesforce-platform-developer-1-certificate-and-the-o

Answer (score 0):

In 2018, the Dev 401 cert will no longer be an active certification. Salesforce has a video that you can watch that will help you with this transition. But there is the Platform App Builder cert which is the "transition" certification before taking Platform Dev 1 and Dev 2. Here is the link: [Developer Certifications](https://www.youtube.com/watch?t=3&v=wM5Th-ComR4)

Platform Dev 1 focuses on basic coding skills where as Platform Dev 2 is a more advanced test focusing on advanced coding skills with Apex and Visualforce.